# LLDB: print string with line breaks in a pretty fashion

Tags: lldb

In LLDB when I print a string containing line breaks it prints `\n` which messes up the entire output (especially for C++ string types). Is there a flag/option/whatever to tell LLDB to really print linebreaks instead of the escaped variants?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(lldb) setting set escape-non-printables false
```

Will do what you want - cfr.

```
(lldb) p @"Hello World\nYes I mean it"
(__NSCFString *) $0 = 0x0000000100b00180 @"Hello World
Yes I mean it"
```

vs. the default

```
(lldb) p @"Hello World\nYes I mean it"
(__NSCFString *) $1 = 0x0000000100b00000 @"Hello World\nYes I mean it"
```

Comment: Sorry, I just realize I forgot to mention this is for C++ code (e.g. std::string and std:wstring).

Comment: The same exact command should work for you - I just happened to be debugging an ObjC inferior at the time and used that to cons up the example

Comment: Indeed that command works, but is there a way to make this permanent? Atm I have run it every time a new debug session starts.

Comment: You should be able to just put that command in your ~/.lldbinit file and then LLDB will source it at the start of every debug session

Comment: Doesn't work for me under macOS 13.0, Xcode 14.1. I tried `p` `e` and `po` but they all still print `\n` instead of the actual line breaks.

Comment: `e print(variable)` works for me! (Using Swift, under ObjC it should be `e NSLog(@"%@", variable)` to get the same result)